# Are there any cases where the mediant chord has dominant function?

Tags: harmony

In my knowledge, each diatonic chord has diatonic functions:

- I, iii, vi - **Tonic** function
- ii, IV - **Subdominant** function
- V, vii<sup>o</sup> - **Dominant** function

The question is, are there any cases where iii has dominant function instead, as it contains the leading tone?

Comment: The linked "answer" provides not cases/examples of a mediant chord functioning as a dominant. It simply mentions the common tones between the two chords. This question deserves an answer _showing how it can function as a dominant_.

Comment: Alright, that's good enough for me. If no one can give any examples, though, I think it should be reclosed.